# Delete faces inside generated meshes on surface

Tags: geometry-nodes

How additionally to delete faces inside spheres?
Without boolean!
[image]

Comment: you can do that with raycast. But sorry, i am lazy. I you don't provide a blend file, i have no desire to rebuild your node tree....

Comment: raycast the option if you have flat surface, but if your surface like suzanne you delete all in infinite range

Comment: therefore you can use the ray length of raycast node...so sorry, but your statement is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Chris says, you should probably use `Raycast` for this and compare the direction of the *Hit Normals* to the *Position*s of the plane vertices via `Dot Product`. Since they're all spheres, i.e. self-contained manifold islands, there's no concern about raycasts hitting unwanted faces that could produce false alarms. If you want a larger boundary around the spheres to be deleted, you can still use the `Geometry Proximity` setup you have after raycasting:

[image]

[image]

Comment: have a trouble with this method on Suzanne with subd lvl4

Comment: What kind of trouble? It works for me: https://i.imgur.com/5OpKUYt.png Suzanne's actually not entirely manifold, her eyes are not connected to the rest of her head, maybe that's causing problems for you somehow if your grid on her eye level or sth?

Comment: Nevermind, I see you mean Subd of the grid, not Suzanne. Happened to me as well, investigating.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2MZKeX8.png https://i.imgur.com/3y8KsaQ.png I meant like this (ignore the crossed out circle)

Comment: I applied sds lvl4 on suzanne

Comment: @APEC Actually, I don't seem to have that problem: https://i.imgur.com/Ov6Zn4y.png I'm updating the answer with a link to the file as well.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark the answer as accepted then please? Also, did you find out why yours wasn't working?

Comment: I used "Is Hit" instead of "Hit Normal". Thanks again! I made it as an answer.